# Erlang, register/2: exception error bad argument

Tags: erlang

I want to write program which creates 2  processes.
First print number , send it to second process and so on.
However I have problem in start function.

```
-module(zad).

-export([start/0, one/0, two/0]).

one() ->
    receive
        {go1, N} ->
            io:format("1 ~w~n", [N]),
            two ! {go2, N+1},
            one();
        {go2, 50} ->
            io:format("END ~w~n", [N+1]),
            two ! finished
    end.

two() ->
    receive
        finished ->
            io:format("two finished~n", []);
        {go2, N} ->
            io:format("2 ~w~n", [N]),
            one ! {go1, N+1 },
            two()
    end.

start() -> 
    register(two, spawn(zad, two, [])),
    register(one, spawn(zad, one, [])),
    one ! {go1, 0}.
```

here's error

```
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  register/2
    called as register(two,<0.146.0>)
 in call from zad:start/0 (zad.erl, line 29)
```

Does it mean that I cant register 2 processes in start? What is wrong with this code?

**UPDATE**
It is really weird. but after I changed

```
{go2, 50} -> io:format("END ~w~n", [N+1]),
```

to

```
{go2, 50} -> io:format("END ~w~n", [50]),
```

error disappeared. 
It's really strange because problem is in `one()`, but error was in `register(two)`

Comment: Perhaps there was a syntax error in `two/0` as well? Perhaps a change in `two/0` hadn't been compiled and when you recompiled for `one/0` it was corrected?

Comment: How many times have you tried running this? If you run it a second time without unregistering the names then you will an error when you try to reregister a name as the name is already in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register two processes in `start/0`. It means the values you are passing into `register/2` are wrong. From the documentation(http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#register-2):

> Failures:
>
> - `badarg` If PidOrPort is not an existing local process or port.
> - `badarg` If RegName is already in use.
> - `badarg` If the process or port is already registered (already has a name). `badarg` If RegName is the atom `undefined`.

Likely what has happened is the process died before `register/2` was called (see the first failure in the list above).